# Smooth Scroll of Child Elements Onclick with Active / Inactive Arrow Buttons

Tags: jquery, css

Straight-up honesty, looking for a bit of help to complete a work project!

Ok, I have a centered container on a page with scrollable child elements:

```
 <div class ="project-wrap">
   <div class="project-detail" id="project-detail1"></div>
   <div class="project-detail" id="project-detail2"></div>
   <div class="project-detail" id="project-detail3"></div>
   .
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

What I am looking for is a CSS or jQuery solution where the user can smoothly scroll between each .project-detail by clicking an "up" or "down" arrow with the caveat that when the first child is in view, the up arrow is disabled / inactive / lower opacity, and conversely when the last child is in view the "down" arrow is similarly disabled / inactive / lower opacity via a class change eg. ".inactive".

Thanks and much appreciation for any ideas!

addendum: Just to be clear, the parent container (.project-wrap) is where the scrolling occurs not the body or html page as a whole.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post the code you have so far, and could you break down your question into smaller chunks? As it is right now, your question is fairly broad and you haven't given us a ton of code to work with. You might consider posting your html/javascript into a jsFiddle or codepen or something like that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a quick and dirty solution for you. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/Gdg59/1/).

It's fairly simple and could use some improvement (caching of variables, error checking, etc.), but it should point you in the right direction:

```
$(".project-wrap").scroll(function(e) {
   var currentScrollInDiv = $(".project-wrap").scrollTop();
    if (currentScrollInDiv <= detailPositions[0]) {
        $("#down").removeClass("inactive");
        $("#up").addClass("inactive");
    } else if (currentScrollInDiv >= detailPositions[detailPositions.length-1]) {
        $("#up").removeClass("inactive");
        $("#down").addClass("inactive");
    } else {
        $(".scrollButton").removeClass("inactive");
    }
});

$("#up").click(function(e) {
    var currentScrollInDiv = $(".project-wrap").scrollTop();
    var scrollTo = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<detailPositions.length; i++) {
        scrollTo = (detailPositions[i]<currentScrollInDiv-1) ? detailPositions[i] : scrollTo; //avoid rounding errors
    }
    $(".project-wrap").scrollTop(scrollTo);
});
$("#down").click(function(e) {
    var currentScrollInDiv = $(".project-wrap").scrollTop();
    var scrollTo = null;
    for (var i=detailPositions.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        scrollTo = (detailPositions[i]>currentScrollInDiv+1) ? detailPositions[i] : scrollTo; //avoid rounding errors
    }
    if (scrollTo) $(".project-wrap").scrollTop(scrollTo);
});

var detailPositions = [];

$('.project-detail').each(function() {
    detailPositions.push($(this).position().top);
});
```

If you have any questions or difficulties, let me know. (Also, next time try to post more of your code and ask for help with more discrete problems.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, I modified your suggestion to fit into the scheme I am working with, seems to work so far except that when the last .project-detail is in view, the down arrow does not get the inactive class applied

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modernpostism/7Subf/1/)

Comment: @modernpostism That's probably because your last `.project-detail` doesn't take up the whole height of the div. Try the modifications in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/Gdg59/1/).

Comment: @modernpostism If this answer solved your problem, I would be grateful if you could mark it as answered. Hope your project is going well!